# Javascript and saving information to file

Tags: javascript, ajax

With AJAXs help it's posible to load data from file, but is it possible to save a value of string variable to file? I want to hold data in file with .txt extension and load it when I will need it.

Comment: Yes, just send this string data to your backend file and write this string to an existing file or new file in the backend file. Maybe I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: you can create a datauri.... where are you trying to save the file

Comment: Which server side language does your application use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Create and save file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a server side. Assuming you do, send the data back and forth via GET/POST, and edit/save it from the server side. Unless you want the user to pick the file themselves, you can use the FileReader js object with . Otherwise, for security reasons, you cannot. That would give your system access to any user's home directories on their machine.